# SqlCeDataAdapter returning only one row

Tags: c#, datatable, sql-server-ce

I'm using SQL server Ce and trying to get AuthorID `from table Author where fName + ' ' + lName = textBox3.text`

the query must return 2 Author IDs (2 Rows) stored in a DataTable, but I'm only getting one row with the first Author Id only

```
public static DataTable Select(string sql)
    {
        SqlCeDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();           
        DataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string[] authors = textBox6.Text.Split(',');
        DataTable dt;
        string sql = @"select AuthorID from Author where ((fName + ' ' + lName = '" + authors[0] + @"')";
        for (int i = 0; i < authors.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != authors.Length - 1)
            {
                sql += @"OR (fName + ' ' + lName = '" + authors[++i] + @"'))";                    
            }
        }
        dt = Form1.Select(sql);            
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        for (int i = 0; i < authors.Length; i++)
        {
            Form1.Query(@"insert into Book_Author ([ISBN], AuthorID) values (" + ISBN + ", " + dt.Rows[i]["AuthorID"] + ")");
        }
```

any help??

Comment: Could you please show your full code? It is hard to read like this one..

Comment: @user3212556 Edit your question. Add code there.

Comment: Please edit your question and insert your code.

Comment: @rockstartprogrammer
done